# Realm check if value of first column greater than value of second column

Tags: android, sqlite, realm

I'm changing my application from SQLite to Realm and I have next question.

I have next SQLite statement and I want to convert into Realm:

```
 SELECT * from Table1 WHERE Table1.column1 = ? 
 AND Table1.column2 = ? 
 AND Table1.column3 < Table1.column4;
```

Comment: This is actually not a bad question, but I don't think this type of queries is supported yet. In fact, I can't seem to find an issue for it either as a possible enhancement. Anyways, the workaround for now in scenarios like this is that in the setter of `column3` and setter of `column4`, you also update a relevant boolean value that you do the query upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While that sort of query is supported by the underlying storage engine, that capability is not yet exposed in the Java API. You can follow https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1615 for progress on that.